# Loaded content brokes the submenu toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a website that has a menu and a submenu on the header.

I'm loading on the html the header this way (this script is in the bottom of the html file):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#header').load('includes/header.html', function(){
        });
    </script>
```

The problem is that when I load the header that way, this script (that works if I have the header on the same html) stops working (this script is in the main.js file):

```
    function mainmenu(){
    // hide submenu
    $(" ul#mainnav ul ").css({display: "none"});
    // Defino que submenus deben estar visibles cuando se pasa el mouse por encima
    $(" ul#mainnav li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first:hidden').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
        },function(){
            $(this).find('ul:first').slideUp(400);
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        mainmenu();
    });
```

Why does it stops working when on a loaded html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `on` to make sure the elements "always" have the events bound to them. For example, I would think you'd need something like this:

```
function mainmenu() {
    $("#header").on({"mouseenter": function () {
        $(this).find('ul:first:hidden').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
    }, "mouseleave": function () {
        $(this).find('ul:first').slideUp(400);
    }}, "ul#mainnav li");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    mainmenu();
});
```

Comment: I have to tell you that with the edit you have just made it doesn't work, it fixed with your first answer

Comment: @diego I think I missed a `}` and I fixed that as you made that comment

Comment: @diego I'm not sure which one of those variations is "better", but as you point out, they both seem to work. I'd stick with the most recent one, because it's only one call to `on`